# Доступ к json в зависимости от значений переменных

Tags: javascript, json

Имеется json файл с кучей объектов. "Адреса" этих объектов я хочу хранить в какой-либо переменной либо массиве, но адекватных решений я не нашел.

Например, имеется файл json с названием city:

```
{
"1":{"foo":"1","bar":{"m":"yes"}},
"2":{"oof":"-1","bra":{"t":"no"}}
}
```

Чтобы получить значение "foo", мне нужно обратиться к json файлу вот так: `city["1"].foo`, но если я хочу брать названия "адресов" из переменных, то парсер поймёт это как название адреса, а не переменные, с которых нужно взять значения:

`var note = 15
var velocity = 100
city.note.velocity` <- обратится к адреcу city.note.velocity, а не city["15"].["100"]

Comment: Вы же уже знаете про квадратные скобки: `var foo = "oof"; console.log(city["1"].[foo]); // -1`

Comment: Господи, как же я затупил. Оставьте этот комментарий как решение, я помечу вопрос как решенный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы же уже знаете про квадратные скобки:

```js
var city = {
  "1": { "foo": "1", "bar": { "m": "yes" } },
  "2": { "oof": "-1", "bra": { "t": "no" } }
};
var foo = "oof"; 
console.log(city["2"][foo]); // -1
```